# MySQL DELETE statement with multiple tables fails with error

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I have a script that needs to delete data from multiple tables on a MySQL database. The version of MySQL I am running is 8.0.32. I am using the DELETE statement (and not the DROP statement) since I only want to delete the data itself, not the schema. The statement I used looks like this:

`DELETE FROM table1, table2`

When I ran this statement in MySQL shell I get the following error message:

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax;

I searched Google for this error message but couldn't find an answer related to my specific issue since this is just a generic error complaining about the syntax being wrong.

I looked through MySQL's documentation on the DELETE statement and it does look like the DELETE statement supports deletion of multiple tables in one statement. This is what I found:
(https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/delete.html)

The two tables I tried to delete do not have foreign keys or any other relationship with each other. They are not related at all. Any ideas why this statement is failing?

I tried running the DELETE statements using different syntax. I tried running it with only one table and it worked.

Comment: You can use the DELETE statement to delete data from multiple tables based on a relationship between them:

 

DELETE table1, table2
FROM table1
INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.column = table2.column
WHERE condition;

In this example, table1 and table2 are the tables you want to delete data from, and column is the column that relates the two tables. condition is the condition that specifies which rows to delete.

Comment: What if these two tables don't have a column on which you can join. For example, I have a table called users, with a user ID (PK), a username and email address. I also have product table, which has a product ID, a product name and price. These tables do not share any data in common. My confusion is, how come you can use this statement to delete the data from one table with no problems, but the minute you try to do this with multiple tables, even if there are no relationships the statement fails.

Comment: If the tables have no data in common, why would you want to delete from both in the same statement? Just use two statements.

Comment: But to answer your question, you should look at the syntax for multi-table DELETE syntax more carefully. You _must_ reference the tables before the FROM keyword to make it clear which tables you want to delete, because it's a common task to delete from just one of the tables in a join, and you'd definitely want a way to specify that.

Comment: I was thinking of optimizing a script that needs to delete several dozen tables. Running a separate delete statement for each table would make the script a lot longer.

Comment: According to the MySQL documentation, the syntax for a multi-table delete statement is:

DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE]
    tbl_name[.*] [, tbl_name[.*]] ...
    FROM table_references
    [WHERE where_condition]

DELETE [LOW_PRIORITY] [QUICK] [IGNORE]
    FROM tbl_name[.*] [, tbl_name[.*]] ...
    USING table_references
    [WHERE where_condition]
To my understanding, the syntax shows that the table name comes after the FROM keyword, but correct me if I'm wrong.